# Bobblehead works only when scrolling down

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, april-fools, unicoins

The bobblehead feature which shakes user avatars only does so when scrolling *down* the page. When scrolling up, the avatars do not bobble. I paid good unicoins for this!

Comment: Do you own a bobblehead? If so, try pressing the head down. It doesn't really bobble.

Comment: But when I scroll up, the avatars go down...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a physical question, but a legal one.

As commentators in the Arnold Schwarzenegger Bobblehead Doll War have noted<sup>1</sup> (emph. added),

> The **very act of creating** a bobblehead doll out of an individual's likeness **sufficiently distorts** the likeness beyond a mere literal depiction to create the intended **comic** effect characteristic of bobblehead dolls.

According to this legal scholar, the actual movement is irrelevant. The *making* of a bobblehead alone is funny in and of itself. Please laugh now.

In addition, the article argues that a bobblehead is an, albeit untraditional, medium of expression that is protected under the First Amendment to the US Constitution. And that is just lawyer-speak for "When it comes to bobbleheads, we can do whatever we please."

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>William T. Gallagher, *Strategic Intellectual Property Litigation, the Right of Publicity, and the Attenuation of Free Speech: Lessons from the Schwarzenegger Bobblehead Doll War (and Peace)*, Santa Clara Law Review, Vol. 45, 2005, Page 595</sup>

Comment: (in all seriousness: the first version bobbled in both scroll directions, and it looked weird when scrolling up)

Comment: Close: off-topic. Legal questions are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange network. I always thought employees were held to higher standards -- now I see the truth.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>*This answer may be recorded for quality control purposes*</sup>

Consider asking this question on [Physics Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/227403/edit), which discusses bobblehead-physics related issues rather than unicorns.

Though to be a good sport, I will give you a link-only answer to the [Second Law of Thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) and [Perpetual Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) which it states is impossible as a result.